# Icons not showing, programs not launching after installing packages w/ unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, icons

none of my programs are unable to launch,even the system programs such as "Terminal".
I ran the following two commands:
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`
and after that I restarted the system and it showed the follwing error: "An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: ' Error: BrokenCount>0' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies"
[image]

Comment: Without knowing what you did, we really cannot help. You can access virtual terminals in `ctrl + alt + f3`, and in principle rescue the system from there. But it may be much easier to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thanks a ton for the `ctrl + alt + f3` tip! I ran `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` from tty4, this seem to have fixed my issue

Comment: You can write that as your own answer.